# Mod_rewrite doesn't work for a url beginning in % (percent sign)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, symbols, pagerank

There are several links pointing to a site I manage in which the webmaster mistakenly **included a space** between the domain name and the page name:

```
    www.domain.com/ page.html
```

When the user clicks, this gives

```
    www.domain.com/%20page.html
```

I'd like to use mod_rewrite to redirect hits to the incorrect address to the correct address, but **my rewrite rule is not working**. I have tried the following without success:

```
    rewriterule ^\%20page.html$ /page.html [R=301,L]
    rewriterule ^.20page.html$ /page.html [R=301,L]
```

**How can I write a rule to catch this address?** I'd like to keep the PageRank and not be penalized for a broken link, and I can't get the webmaster to fix his links.

Comment: You have a webmaster that doesn't fix broken links?  That seems like an impressively bad situation.

Comment: If the links are broken, I doubt you have a PageRank at all, so fix the links.  If your webmaster won't fix them, that's a major problem.  That's his job, and its inexcusable that he wrote them that way in the first place...

Comment: The links are from an external site with which I no longer have contact, and I'd prefer not to ask them -- they might remove the link instead of fixing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the space in your RewriteRule.  Probably by the time mod_rewrite sees it, it's been decoded.

Comment: rewriterule ^.page.html$ /page.html [R=301,L] worked, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, you really ought to embed the space.  RoBorg specified how you actually do that, which I should've.

Answer (score 7):

Use a literal space, escaped with a backslash so it doesn't end the regular expression:

```
RewriteRule ^\ page.html$ /page.html [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this to remove all control characters:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\x00-\x19\x7F]*)[\x00-\x19\x7F]+(.*) /$1$2 [L,R=301]
```

And for your additional space character:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\x00-\x20\x7F]*)[\x00-\x20\x7F]+(.*) /$1$2 [L,R=301]
```